# Ubuntu 16.04 how to use ping in a bash script to decide whether to skip a block of code

Tags: bash, ping

I have data loggers spread around the solar power system, and a single program that runs at midnight to collect the day's data and put it on a hard drive.

The bash script on the Ubuntu server steps through 7 Raspbian units that have the data collected and puts it in the proper place on the hard drive, in directories named by the units out there.  I figured out how to take the generic names today.dat and today.png and save them with the day's date in the archive like 2017-08-10.png and 2017-08-10.dat

-->  Occasionally one of the units will not respond due to some problem or other, and it blocks execution of the program.

So I would like to use ping to test whether the system responds before I decide whether to try to gather data from it.

My system names are all in the /etc/hosts file so I reference them by name.

For purposes of this question I am checking SOLAR - the one that monitors the charge controller and inverter behavior.

Here is what I have tried:

```
if $( ping -c 1 SOLAR | grep icmp* | wc -l ) eq 0
then
   (do stuff like ssh -e "gnuplot makepng" then scp the png and raw data)
fi
```

(too complicated)

and

```
if [ $(ping -c 1 SOLAR >/dev/null) eq 0 ]
    then do the stuff
fi
```

(looks OK but I don't understand the need for the square brackets)

There must be a better way.

I am hoping to do something more like

```
if $(ping -c 1 SOLAR) eq 0
then
   (do stuff)
else
   (then maybe echo "SOLAR didn't respond" | ssmtp myname@gmail.com
fi
```

I haven't programmed bash in a couple of decades - used C shell most of the time.  And I am getting way too much varying advice all over the net about the best way to do this.

So can anybody please suggest a simple way to do this?

Comment: You know to write `foo eq 0`, but don't know why `[ ]` is needed or that it's `-eq`? You need a bash tutorial.

Comment: What can I say? I'm flattered you took the time to go through my 2500+ answers on SE to conclude that I couldn't write such an answer.

Comment: Good point.  Shifting from C Shell to bash (when I used to use korn long ago) is requiring some tutoring.  And yes I have seen a lot of examples where you do so quite thoroughly, @muru, so I take that back.  -->  In any case, while you were weighing in about my lack of ability (the reason I had to ask the question), the answer was simultaneously being written and within a couple of hours was incorporated into my program, where it will now save me time every day.

Comment: it wasn't the lack of ability so much as the danger - say you wrote something that looks it works, but that was actually due to a quirk of syntax, and you deploy it somewhere where it can cause actual damage due to some edge case you couldn't test...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are only interested in the exit status of `ping` i.e. whether you are getting ICMP ECHO_RESPONSE from the host to your ECHO_REQUEST; you can just do `ping -c 1 ...` and `ping` would exit with status `0` if the host is sending response, `1` if no response and `2` for unknown host.

You can easily use this with `if` construct; you don't need to count response, just use `ping` as `if`'s condition as `if` would evaluate the exit status of `ping` to proceed to any defined branch:

```bsh
if ping -c 1 SOLAR &>/dev/null; then
    ## Reachable -- do stuffs
else
    ## Unreachable -- do other stuffs
fi
```

I am redirecting `ping`'s STDOUT and STDERR streams to `/dev/null` as we are not interested in those.

Comment: So the if statement will evaluate success or failure and I don't need to check the numerical return value, eh?  This is short and sweet - just what I have been looking for.  Thank you.

Comment: @SDsolar Read it as `if true` (exit status is not like the return value BTW). `$()` is called command substitution, it has specific use cases but not needed here.

Comment: Thank you again, @heemayl.  You have helped me a lot.  I was having the midnight program email me a log file and needed to look at it carefully each day to catch anomalies.  Now I get email alerts regarding only those sensors in need of a touch of TLC.  That's a HUGE improvement.  TNX AGN.

Comment: @SDsolar Great. Glad I could help :)